# What are the pros and cons of using big tires in front on a bike?

Tags: motorcycle, tires, wheels

I need to know more about the pros and cons of using different size tires in front and back. My bike has a lower curb weight, so every time its back tire skids.

Comment: Please give us more information about the problem you're having.

Comment: Voted to close, not because the idea of the question is bad, but because it is incomplete. Provide more information about the specific motorcycle and the exact problem you are having, and we shall consider reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tire size is specified by the manufacturer. They specify the size based on their frame geometry and other characteristics of the bike. If you have a problem with the rear wheel  skidding you have to address the cause of the brake malfunction. It may be as simple as over application of the rear brake and under application of the front brake. You may have a brake that is grabbing due to contamination of the linings or a mechanical issue such as broken  brake mounting hardware. You may also have misadjusted or worn front suspention forks. If the front end is diving excessively during braking the weight on the rear wheel shifts to the front making the rear wheel more likely to lock up and skid.

Comment: +1 for the overapplication of rear brake.  Also a larger width front tyre would normally have a shallower profile and therefore slow turning into corners down.  Like you said, manufacturers specify a tyre size for a reason.